# Why does the variable passed in locals object becomes undefined on reahing ejs file?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am new to Node and Express. I was using DOG API to get an object containing all breeds of dogs and then rendering them using ejs.
Below is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = 8000;

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var request = require('request');
    var obj;
    request('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            obj = JSON.parse(body);
            obj = obj.message;
            console.log("hello ", obj);
        }
    });
    res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', dogBreeds: obj });
});

app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log("ERROS: ",err);
    }
    console.log("Express server is runnig on port: ",port);
});
```

I have views folder which contains `index.ejs` file
Below is my `index.ejs` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
        <%= title  %>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>How r u?</h1>
    <p>
        <%= dogBreeds["waterdog"] %>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I typed: `http://localhost:8000/` in the browser and ran the server. The output on the console is:
`hello` *followed by the complete object fetched*

But in the `ejs` file when I try to fetch properties of dogBreeds object it says:
**Cannot read property '*property-name*' of undefined**
Why does this happen? OR Am I going wrong somewhere?

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing asynchronous things like sending a request they take some time to resolve(Even if the server is extremely fast at giving the response note that the callback function doesn't execute immediately). In your get route, you're sending the request and trying to render the ejs file immediately..you should wait for the response instead.

Move your render part inside the block where you're getting the response.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var request = require('request');
    var obj;
    request('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            obj = JSON.parse(body);
            obj = obj.message;
            console.log("hello ", obj);
        }
    });
    res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', dogBreeds: obj });
});
```

should be:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var request = require('request');
    var obj;
    request('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            obj = JSON.parse(body);
            obj = obj.message;
            console.log("hello ", obj);
            res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', dogBreeds: obj });
        }
    });
});
```

Doing this will ensure that you're only rendering once you got the response.